# Showing that $d(x,y)=|(1/x)-(1/y)|$ is a metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am tasked with showing that $d(x,y)=|(1/x)-(1/y)|$ is a metric for all $x,y$ in $(0,\infty)$.

It is obvious that $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$, and also that $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$. However, I am totally stumped on proving the triangular inequality. Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, if $X$ is a set, and $(Y,\delta)$ a metric space and $f\colon X\to Y$ an injective function, then $d(x,y):=\delta(f(x),f(y))$ is a metric on $X$.

This be be easier to show than your the special case.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In this case, if I were to prove your statement, would I let $f(x)=1/x$ be the injective function? A little confused on that part.

Comment: @DavidS of course! The point is that the exact function matters not one iota.

Comment: Got it. Do you know if this theorem has a name or if there's a wiki page that discusses it?

Answer (score 1):

In general way, $d(x,y)=|f(x)-f(y)|$, for any injective "real" map $f$, is a metric.

For the triangular inequality, it follows from the triangular inequality for real numbers. In fact, we have for all $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$d(x,z)=|f(x)-f(z)|=|(f(x)-f(y))+ (f(y)-f(z))|\leq |f(x)-f(y)|+|f(y)-f(z)|=d(x,y)+d(y,z).$$
In your case $f(x)=1/x$. More general case is discussed in the above answer.